# Examining whether $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\mathbb{R}$ space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the usual gradient multiplication, but we define addition on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as follows:

$$(x, y) + (r, s) = (x + r, 2y + s)$$
Examine whether $\mathbb{R}^2$ with these operations is $\mathbb{R}$ space?

I am aware of how to prove that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\mathbb{R}$ space, but the specific formula of addition confuses me in order to apply the conditions. I would appreciate it if you could provide me with your guidance.

Comment: I suggest that you look at the axioms of a vector space and try to check those ones one by one.

Comment: Is R, $\mathbb{R}$? What is an R space?

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a coordinate space over the real numbers. This means that it is the set of the n-tuples of real numbers (sequences of n real numbers). 
Could you please provide me with an example that shows hot to implement the addition above?

Comment: You need to learn to use the right words for things or people won't know what you're talking about. I've never heard of "gradient multiplication"; you meant something about scalar multiples. And nobody knows what an "$\Bbb R$ space" is; you meant _vector space_ (or "real vector space").

Answer (score 1):

Associativity of the addition fails. A calculation yields $$((a,b)+(c,d))+(e,f)=(a+c,2b+d)+(e,f)=(a+c+e,2(2b+d)+f)=(a+c+e,4b+2d+f)$$ whereas $$(a,b)+((c,d)+(e,f))=(a,b)+(c+e,2d+f)=(a+c+e,2b+2d+f).$$

There's no hope for this being even a group.

Alternatively, commutativity obviously fails as well.

Comment: Understood! Thank you very much for your precious help!